# Tooltips with prototype or scriptaculous for magento

Tags: magento, tooltip, prototypejs

I have problem with tooltips on my magento website, I need to have one tooltip on product page which will show a HTML UL List. I tried some plugins I found but had problems with JQuery as it was disabling other prototype pop up I have on product page.

Im really a newbie at All the types of javascript and hope you experts can help me with this please.

My trigger id for tooltips is #why-to-buy
and the tooltip class in CSS is .why-to-buy-tooltip

can anyone suggest me a prototype or scriptaculous driven simple tooltip which can show HTML please?

Any help is more than welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically this can be done in just CSS. To start with there needs to be an anchor;

```
<a id="why-to-buy" href="#" onclick="return false;">
    Why To Buy?
    <ul class="why-to-buy-tooltip">
        <li>Reason #1</li>
        <li>Reason #2</li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

The `onclick` is to prevent it working as a hyperlink. An anchor is necessary for older IEs to respect the following hover;

```css
#why-to-buy {
    position: relative;
}

#why-to-buy .why-to-buy-tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 100;
}

#why-to-buy:hover .why-to-buy-tooltip, #why-to-buy:active .why-to-buy-tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

If you need more info search for and read about "CSS popups". A nice touch is to add some CSS3 transitions - old browsers just ignore them and continue to work as normal.

---

This type of popup is limited because it is inside an anchor, and anchors cannot contain anchors. If the `#why-to-buy` element is of another type, such as a DIV, then IE doesn't pick up the `:hover` pseudoclass. For this special case a bit of JavaScript is needed after all.

```javascript
$('why-to-buy').observe('mouseenter', function() {
    this.addClassName('over');
}).observe('mouseleave', function() {
    this.removeClassName('over');
});
```

Update the last stylesheet rule to include `#why-to-buy.over .why-to-buy-tooltip`. The bit of JavaScript is rarely needed and can go in `/skin/frontend/base/default/js/ie6.js`. Or you could encourage browser upgrades and choose not to support old IE at all.

Comment: Thanks @cloclworkgeek

I guess I can go without javascript this way. You made my day my friend : )) 

Cheers.. and Thank you again! : ))

Clock work Orange reference? : ))

Comment: I have one more question. I really love the way it works but for the future I may need to put some active HTML in tooltip, like links or smth, at the moment, it displays as an image and you cant select a text or link in tooltip.

is it possible to do smth like that in this CSS tooltips? 

thank you : ))

Comment: Hello again guys : ))

This tooltip is working just fine. I just wanted to ask if there is any way to use multiple tooltips on same page, like if I used div class instead of div id? How can I make it work ? 

thank you!

Comment: The CSS part is easy, just change `#why-to-buy` to the class name that's replacing it. For IE's specific javascript you'll need to change `$('why-to-buy').observe...` to `$$('.new-classname').each(function(el) { el.observe... })`. It's not as pretty but fairly standard for Prototype.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google searched returned this one, and shows to support HTML:

http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip/

It's prototype based so should work well with Magento.

Comment: Thanks for response @BOOMER. I Appreciate your input.  
I've gone through the "Quick Google" search results, I wouldnt ask it here otherwise : ))  
Ive found some results and was not able to use them for different reasons. The link you gave me is around $70 for commercial use and magento obviously is commercial.  
Unfortunately i cant afford to pay $70 at this moment for the tooltip plugin.  
Can you point any other solutions please, if you happen to know any?  

Thank You!